# would have had to vs had to

Tags: sentence-construction

Here is the excerpt from a website :

> Black teens were 21 times as likely as white teens to be shot and
> killed by police between 2010 and 2012, according to a ProPublica
> analysis of the FBI data. Ryan Gabrielson reported for ProPublica:
> "One way of appreciating that stark disparity, ProPublica’s analysis
> shows, is to calculate how many more whites over those three years
> would have had to have been killed for them to have been at equal
> risk. The number is jarring — 185, more than one per week." Could I
> rewrite this sentence like :

1.how many more whites over those three years **had to be killed** for them to **be** at equal risk.

2.how many more whites over those three years **had to be killed** for them to **have been** at equal risk.

3.how many more whites over those three years **would have to have been killed** for them to **be** at equal risk.

4.how many more whites over those three years **would have to have been killed** for them to **have been** at equal risk.

5.how many more whites over those three years **would have had to be killed** for them to **have been** at equal risk.

6.how many more whites over those three years **would have had to be killed** for them to **be** at equal risk.

7.how many more whites over those three years **would have had to have been killed** for them to **be** at equal risk.

What are the differences ?

Comment: Why rewrite something that is fine? What's the point of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Non-native here. Yet I'll give this one a shot.

> One way of appreciating that stark disparity [...] is to calculate *how
> many more whites over those three years would have had to have been
> killed for them to have been at equal risk*.

The italicized sentence is AFAIK a so-called [*interrogative noun clause*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause), i.e. a question (*How many...?*) that's been tossed around a little bit to serve as the object of the preceding infinitive (*calculate*).

For clarity's sake, let's isolate the sentence in question, and let's turn it into a regular declarative sentence (I'll be omitting the adverbial phrase *"over those three years"*):

> *185 whites would have had to have been killed for them to have been at
> equal risk.*

In my view, this is a [conditional sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence), albeit somewhat implied.
Let me introduce an extra element to elucidate my point:

> *185 whites **would have had to** have been killed
>
> **if the goal had been** for them to be at equal risk.*

This is a pretty neat example of the [3rd conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Third_conditional):
It refers to a hypothetical situation that's *both* in a *past time frame* (between 2010 and 2012) *and* [*counterfactual*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional) (officially, the goal has never been for anyone to be at risk). Therefore, the [implied] antecedent (*If the goal had been*) is in the past perfect, and the consequent (*185 whites would have had to have been killed*) is in the conditional perfect: *would have had to*...

Compare this to *"would have to..."* from your own example sentences #3 and #4.
To me, this looks like the consequent of a [2nd conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional), which –as per my previous rephrasing, with the introduction of an explicit antecedent– would be:

> *185 whites **would have to** have been killed
>
> **if the goal was** for them to be at equal risk.*

It's still counterfactual, but it doesn't refer to a past-time frame: If the goal (now) was to have the whites at equal risk, then 185 of them would have to have been killed (or 'be killed' – see below).

(Note that [mixed conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Mixed_conditional) also occur, but my guess is that it would be difficult to construe them as such in this particular context, given that the antecedent is merely implied.)

---

On to the trickier stuff:

What's the difference between your own example sentences #5 or #6 on the one hand, and #7 (or the quoted text) on the other?

As per my analysis above, they are all instances of the 3rd conditional.
Adding the perfect infinitive (*have been killed*) after the conditional perfect (*would have had to*), however, seems to further reinforce the *pastness* and the *counterfactuality* that have already been conveyed by the use of the 3rd conditional:

> *185 whites would have had to **have been killed**
>
> [if the goal had been] for them to be at equal risk.*

This is basically like saying that in this "expired" and counterfactual scenario (if such a goal had been set...), we would need to be able to confirm that 185 whites have already been killed in order to claim that they are at equal risk. This kind of parsing is consistent with the analyst's/statistician's approach: You observe what has already happened in order to make claims. It also places the implied agent (*killed by whom?*) on a far more abstract (and seemingly irrelevant) level.

By contrast:

> *185 whites would have had to **be killed**
>
> [if the goal had been] for them to be at equal risk*

is like saying that in this "expired" and counterfactual scenario (if such a goal had been set...), someone would need to start killing whites, until 185 are down, in order for us to claim that whites are at equal risk.

The whole point becomes, perhaps, even more lucid, if we make the same comparison in the 2nd conditional:

> *185 whites would have to **have been killed**
>
> if the goal was for them to be at equal risk*.

(as per your own example sentences #3 and #4)

VS

> *185 whites would have to **be killed**
>
> if the goal was for them to be at equal risk.*

(not included in the examples)

(Note, however, that the most sceptical of linguists might argue that this is redundant in the case of the 3rd conditional. The pastness and the counterfactuality are already there. No need to reinforce them.)

---

In your example sentences #1 and #2, the counterfactuality wouldn't be equally clear, and that might lead to controversial interpretations.

---

Lastly, as for the very end of the sentence, I believe that the choice between simple infinitive (*to be at equal risk*) or perfect infinitive (*to have been at equal risk*) has no tangible effect on the meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation helping me a lot.